# How to retrieve Triggered Send Tracking result for an Email Address

Tags: email, send-email

Requirement:

Check if the email sent out by the trigger send was opened

**Issue:** I am unable to get this information for specific email ID(s) by using the Server side JavaScript functions. Initially, to get started, this is what I tried for retrieved details for Open, Bounced, Clicked emails over a date range.

```
var results = tsd.Tracking.TotalByInterval.Retrieve('Send', '04-07-2015', '04-09-2015', 'day');
```

Next, I tried getting the information for specific email id(s) by doing the following. But, this did not return any results.

```
var results = tsd.Tracking.Retrieve({Property:"Email",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"test@test.com"});
```

Any insights on what I am missing or doing incorrectly will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do this via a VF page written using direct objects, is that what you're trying to tell us? If so, you might want to include the contents of your entire VF page.

Comment: Hi,I am trying to do this via Server Side Javascript. I have created Triggered Sends which I am trying to trigger via TriggeredSend.Send from SSJS. Now I need to know if the user opened the email or not.

Comment: In doing it this way, it doesn't appear to me as though you're leveraging the built-in Salesforce Tracking features. I recommend you check SF Help on the subject, assuming you're sending these via SF single email messaging.